# How to convert multiple columns with various category levels to wide format?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, spread

I have the following set of data with multiple columns that correspond: prompt1 with value1, prompt2 with value2, promptn to valuen. Each prompt contains up to 3 different levels of categories.

```
df.1 <- data.frame(prompt1         = c('date', 'company', 'invoice'),
               value1              = c('2017-01-01', 'Tellabs', '23845'),
               prompt2             = c('code', 'city', 'item'),
               value2              = c('B34', 'Ilinois', 'SER0000066'),
               stringsAsFactors    = FALSE)
```

The desired dataframe would be:

```
df.2 <- data.frame(date              = '2017-01-010',
                   company           = 'Tellabs',
                   invoice           = '23845',
                   code              = 'B34',
                   city              = 'Ilinois',
                   item              = 'SER0000066',
                   stringsAsFactors  = FALSE)
```

I have tried spread from tidyr but without success

Comment: All the columns name have the same format? like prompt or value as prefix?

Comment: @Wen, One of the problems is that not all levels have the same length, therefore, when performing the spread there are many NAs, however, the ycw solution was perfect. 10x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using functions from `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df.2 <- df.1 %>%
  gather(Prompt, Column, contains("prompt")) %>%
  gather(Value, Content, contains("value")) %>%
  filter(sub("prompt", "", Prompt) == sub("value", "", Value)) %>%
  select(Column, Content) %>%
  spread(Column, Content) %>%
  select(date, company, invoice, code, city, item)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I'm just trying to learn a little bit more about doing this

Comment: @William I am glad to help. If this solution is helpful, please accept it by marking the green error on the top left corner.